# How to select only rows with values over a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say that I have the following data frame.

```
np.random.seed(0)  # Add seed to reproduce results. 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['id'] = ['CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'FL', 'FL', 'FL']
df['technique'] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three']
df

          A         B         C         D  id technique
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  CA       one
1  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357  CA       two
2 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274  CA     three
3  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  FL       one
4  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096  FL       two
5 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165  FL     three
```

I want to select only those rows when any of the columns has a value greater than 2. So in the above case, I'd get.

```
          A         B         C         D  id technique
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  CA       one
5 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165  FL     three
```

How can I filter across multiple columns without doing something like the following.

```
df[df.A >= 2 | df.B >= 2 | df.C >= 2 | df.D >= 2]
```

Comment: Your example suggests that you want rows with absolute value greater than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `any`

```
df[df.loc[:,'A':'D'].abs().gt(2).any(1)]
Out[219]: 
          A         B         C         D  id technique
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  CA       one
5 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165  FL     three
```